# Given that $\lim_{z\rightarrow0}az-\frac{\ln z}{z!}=\gamma$, find the value of $a$ that gives the quickest convergence

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence, euler-mascheroni-constant

You could prove that $$\lim_{z\rightarrow0}az-\frac{\ln (z!)}{z}=\gamma$$For any $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Where $z!$ is the factorial extended to all real numbers (except negative integers). Which value gives the quickest convergence, and why? I think it is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$, but I don't know how to prove it. I think it is because of the fact that $$\frac{\pi^2z}{12}-\frac{\ln (z!)}{z}>\gamma$$when $z>-1$, while all other values of $a$ are greater only when $z>0$, which makes this function "flatter" near $\gamma$. Is this a valid argument? And if so (or not), is there another proof?

Comment: $z! \to 1$ as $z\to 0$ and $\ln z \to -\infty$ az $z\to 0^+$, whence your limit cannot be true. Maybe you meant $\Gamma(z)=(z-1)!$ in place of $z!$? Even then, the limit would be $0$.

Comment: @Gary Yes, I will specify this. Thanks!

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. $\frac{\ln z}{z!}\to -\infty$ if $z\to 0$. I cannot really see how to modify your expression to end up with $\gamma$.

Comment: @Gary Silly me! I messed up the placement of the factorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Taylor polynomials:
$$
\log (z!) = \log \Gamma (z + 1) =  - \gamma z + \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{{12}}z^2  + \mathcal{O}(z^3 )
$$
as $z\to 0$. See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Taylor_Series_of_Logarithm_of_Gamma_Function) (take $z+1$ in place of $z$).

Comment: But how does this prove that $a=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ is the best choice? I don't see the trick here.

Comment: @KamalSaleh For other $a$, the expression goes to zero at the speed of $z$, but when $a=\pi^2/12$, you get an expression that tends to zero like $z^3$, much faster than $z$.

Comment: @TravorLZH ah, I see now!

Comment: I am actually using this for a paper, so may I cite this answer @Gary?

Comment: @KamalSaleh I think for a paper it is much better if you cite a standard reference book on special functions. In general, you want to cite published papers and books if possible.