# How to modify $(1+x)^{1/x}$ to make it greater than $e$

Tags: calculus, inequality, convergence-divergence

I have the function $(1+x)^{1/x}$, which famously approaches $e$ as $x$ approaches $0$. After studying convergence of functions in general a bit, it seems that if I make a function greater than the number it is converging to (as $x$ approaches a number less than $\infty$), then we will achieve rapid convergence. So is it possible to modify this function so that it is always bigger than $e$ for $x$ but still approaches $e$ near $0$? I have found out that dividing $x$ helps with better convergence, but it doesn't achieve my goal.

Comment: Your "realization" about making convergent functions converge faster  seems false.

Comment: Your function is already greater than $e$ when $-1<x<0$. In general, there is no relationship between rate of convergence and whether the values of the function are greater than or less than the limit. If the function $f(x)$ approaches $L$ and has values less than $L$, then the function $2L-f(x)$ approaches $L$ and has values greater than $L$. But they have the same rate of convergence.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is a bit hard to explain. But take a look at this post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616641/given-that-lim-z-rightarrow0az-frac-ln-zz-gamma-find-the-value-of

Comment: @AlexKruckman It is less than $e$ for positive values

Comment: Yes, but aren't the negative values of $x$ just as relevant as the positive values? If you really care about the positive values, consider the function $(1-x)^{1/(-x)}$ [which substitutes $-x$ for $x$, and hence switches the positive and negative values] or the function $2e - (1+x)^{1/x}$ [as I suggested in my previous comment]. Anyway, as Thomas Andrews says, the whole question is based on a false premise.

Comment: @AlexKruckman If we could modify the function $(1+x)^{1/x}$ to be greater than $e$ but still approach it at $x=0$, then it would be "flatter" on the function $y=e$.

Comment: If $x_n$ converges "slowly" to $L$ and $x_n<L$ for every $n$, then $-x_n$ converges to $-L$ and $-x_n>-L$ but the convergence is still "slow", so your observation is incorrect in general.

Comment: @Taladris I know it is wrong, but it is a bit hard to explain what I want. If I am given a function $f(x)$ that approaches $L$ at $x=c$, then there is a family of functions $f_n(x)$ related to $f(x)$ that also approach $L$ at $x=c$. Take a look at this post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616641/given-that-lim-z-rightarrow0az-frac-ln-zz-gamma-find-the-value-of, and take a look at the answer.

Comment: If you want it to be flatter at 0, then just replace $x$ with $x^2$

Comment: @AlexK Thank you so much! I should've fiddled with the exponent :/

Comment: $(1+x)^{(1+1/x)}>e$ when $1>x>0$.

Comment: @KamalSaleh That example is one very specific limit. It is not a general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take $$  \left( 1 + x  \right)^{\frac{2}{2x-x^2}}  $$

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Cheers!

Comment: Can you please explain the idea behind the scaling with $\frac{2}{2-x}$?

Comment: @Matija  for $x>0,  $  and $x < 1,$  $$ x > \log(1+x)  >  x - \frac{x^2}{2} $$  Now divide through by $  x - \frac{x^2}{2} $

Comment: Very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathcal I\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a function that is defined on some interval $\mathcal I$ with $-\infty<\inf\mathcal I\in\mathcal I$, continuous derivative in a neighborhood of $a=\inf\mathcal I$, and such that the right derivative $f'(a)\in(-\infty,0)$ is finite and negative. Then there exists $\varepsilon$ such that $f'(x)\in(-\infty,0)$ for $x\in[a,a+\varepsilon]$ exists and is negative. Let $D=\min_{x\in[a,a+\varepsilon]}f'(x)$ be the minimum derivative. Then $g:\mathcal I\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $x\mapsto f(x)-D(x-a)$ satisfies $g(a)=f(a)$ and $g'(x)\ge 0$ for $x\le a+\varepsilon$.

If you want to achieve $g'(a)=0$ and $f''$ exists and is continuous close to $a$, we can also do this. For this purpose we consider $f(x)-f'(0)(x-a)+c(x-a)^2$, where we choose $c$ sufficiently large. This in particular works for $(1+x)^{1/x}$.